# How do I use REGEXTRACT to return grouped numbers from a string where the number of groups varies?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regex, regexextract

In Google Sheets, I'm trying to return numbers from within a text string.

The numbers are values of the property named either `item_id` or `item_ids`.

I've tried the REGEXTRACT function but I'm struggling.

### Example 1

1. Text in cell A1

   ```
   <!-- wp:shortcode -->
   [aces-unit-1 item_id=""1236""]
   <!-- /wp:shortcode -->
   ```
2. Expected Result

   ```
   1236
   ```

### Example 2

1. Text in cell A1

   ```
   <!-- wp:shortcode -->
   [aces-bonuses-1 items_number=""4"" external_link=""1"" category="""" items_id=""1563, 2372, 3855, 3980"" exclude_id="""" parent_id="""" columns=""4"" order="""" orderby="""" title=""""]
   <!-- /wp:shortcode -->
   ```
2. Expected Result

   ```
   1563, 2372, 3855, 3980
   ```

Comment: What spreadsheet website are you using?

Comment: if the `item_id` vs `item_ids` is a typo and the string is always one or the other, [edit] your question to fix that and I can update [the solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/172931/).

Answer (score 0):

## Formula

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "items?_id=""""((?:\d{4}[,\s]{0,2})+)""""")
```

## Explanation

1. Matches (non-capture) `(?:)` 4-digit number groups `\d{4}` followed by 0-2 commas and/or spaces `[,\s]{0,2}`
2. Captures one or more of the matched number groups if immediately preceded by `items?_id=""""` and immediately followed by `"""""`

   - the letter **s** is optional (item vs. item**s**) `s?`
   - The consecutive (double) quotes **""** are each escaped with an additional quote `""""`

## #N/A Errors

If there is no match found, the formula returns a `#N/A` error.  This can be handled using the [IFNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) function to return a blank of whatever value is preferred.

```
# IFNA returns nothing/blank 
=IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "items?_id=""""((?:\d{4}[,\s]{0,2})+)"""""))

# IFNA returns something
=IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "items?_id=""""((?:\d{4}[,\s]{0,2})+)"""""),<something>)

// Replace <something> with a string, number, cell reference, formula, etc.
```

[ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) [IFNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944?hl=en)